# How to get the value of Int in [Int : Bool]?

Tags: arrays, uitableview, checkmark

Im Trying to get the value of Int from `[Int : Bool]` so that i can remove the row value from the tableView.

Here's my code.

```
 var checkmarks = [Int : Bool]()

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedNamesIndex = indexPath.row
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    if let index = selectedNamesIndex {
        if (cell?.accessoryType == .checkmark) {
            cell!.accessoryType = .none
            checkmarks[indexPath.row] = false
            hasChecked = false

            let indexPathTapped = tableView.indexPath(for: cell!)
            let name = namelist[(indexPathTapped!.row)]
            print(name, hasChecked)
            selectedNamesToBroadcast.remove(at: checkmarks) // theres an error here: Cannot convert value of type '[Int : Bool]' to expected argument type 'Int'
        } else {
            cell!.accessoryType = .checkmark
            checkmarks[indexPath.row] = true
            hasChecked = true

            let indexPathTapped = tableView.indexPath(for: cell!)
            let name = namelist[(indexPathTapped!.row)]
            print(name, hasChecked)
            selectedNamesToBroadcast.append(name)

            let selectedNamesToBroadcast = name

        }
    }
```

I want to be able to uncheck the color. So that when I update the database, it will be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want

```
if let index = selectedNamesToBroadcast.index(of: name) {
    selectedNamesToBroadcast.remove(at: index)
}
```

Comment: Hi @vadian, thanks for helping, Im getting an error on that line `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range`

Comment: can i ask if theres another way on saving the checkmarks to coredata. its because when i go to another page and back to this page, the checkmarks are gone. Ive seen tutorials about core data but it doest say anything about Bool values.

Comment: Save `Int16` and add a computed property to map 0 to false and 1 to true.

Comment: Is there a tutorial for this? Im still new at coding.

Comment: this is what i get when i `print(checkmarks)` [3: false, 1: false, 4: false, 6: false, 5: false, 7: false, 0: false, 8: false, 9: false, 2: true] if i can just save all the `true` values then load them when I enter the page I think it will work.

Comment: Anyway you should use **one** record for all attributes like `name`, `isChecked` etc. rather than separate arrays and dictionaries

Comment: so that means i can save all the values of `hasChecked` right

Comment: Yes, one record contains the `name` and also the `isChecked` information.

Comment: do i save it in coreData or in some other way? i hope its not coreData hahaha

Comment: If the record contains only a few attributes use a custom struct, serialize it with `Codable` and save it in the documents folder.

Comment: is it this one https://medium.com/@sdrzn/swift-4-codable-lets-make-things-even-easier-c793b6cf29e1

Comment: @Nick Yes, exactly

Comment: thanks @vidian. will try to figure this out. I'll let you know if i succeed or fail hahaha

Comment: Please, this is beyond the scope of this question.